# iframe refuses to acknowledge my php string

Tags: php

I can get the echo to work and the minute I put the php sting in the iframe it shows up blank.  The result is `<iframe src="//galleryPage.php>`
echo result is `"2021DeepFreeze"`

```
   <?php $file = pathinfo(basename(__FILE__), PATHINFO_FILENAME); ?>
        <iframe src="/<?php $file ?>/galleryPage.php" style="width:100%; height:1000px;"  
        </iframe>
```

Comment: You're missing the ending quotes after `src="//galleryPage.php`. Is that a copying error or in the real code?

Comment: Its not at all clear what I’m looking at here. Looks like an iframe embedded in an iframe without a closing tag. What’s the point of this exercise?

Comment: I don't think @Mat's editing actually reflects what's in your PHP and what's in your description of the problem. Please fix the formatting.

Comment: @Mat  ouch. Bad editing on your part. The original was MUCH closer to what is expected.  And my question about iframe embedded in an iframe is for you to answer.

Comment: After looking closely at that last edit I’m thinking the iframe callout has no closing caret >. Additionally we can’t see the path info file name code. Hence the empty directory //

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you forgot to add a ">" to the iframe tag. Right now the tag is <iframe . The second issue is that you forgot to echo the value "$file". So instead of `<?php $file ?>` try `<?php echo $file; ?>` or `<?= $file ?>` <?= is shorthand for echoing a value.